# Android application rejected because it violates the Intellectual Property. What should I do?

Tags: android, google-play, wikimedia, wikimedia-commons

The application fetches the images of famous personalities on runtime via Internet. I have used the image URLs from MediaWiki Commons which is available for public use, but when the application was rejected I emailed Google about the issue and they replied with this.

> Your app contains images of well known entities (Bill Gates, Steve
>   Jobs, Muhammed Ali, Bruce Lee, etc.) that are considered copyrighted.

There are other applications on PlayStore which are using photos of these well known entities.

The image I used for Steve Jobs:-
[Steve Jobs: Commons WikiMedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg)

I would like some suggestions from people who are familiar with this kind of legal issue. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific programming problem. Instead, it's about generic copyright issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal / copyright issues and Google Play's app rejection policy, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are using images from Commons WikiMedia, does not keep you away from possible legal issues.

Please read the [page about reusing content](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia) and also the [terms of use of the license](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg#Licensing)?

Have you for instance, attributed the use of the image to its creator?

> attribution – You must attribute the work in the manner specified by
>   the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they
>   endorse you or your use of the work).

Comment: I read the terms of use Knossos. I have no problem with the attribution, but where do I mention all those things. I have seen that people give credit to the author of the image- right below the image. I have a list where I have an image and the name of the celebrity. It is hard for me to mention about the credit there. 
I am comfortable with crediting the creator of image in a dedicated area of the application ...say Licenses. 
Will it be fine to proceed with?

Comment: IANAL, I can't give you advice how to proceed to make your App legally compatible. If you have a dedicated area, it will need to be a direct click away from the place you are using the image. It should also be tailored to that specific image. As an example, clicking on the image takes you to an activity where it shows the image again, who took it and the license you are using it under.

Comment: thanks, Knossos. I really appreciate your suggestion.